# Wrong merge branchs on Gitlab

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, branch

I have a problem with a merge using a Gitlab interface site (without git commands).

I merge 2 branchs, for example:

featureBranch into releaseBranch (this merge successfully done)

But automatically (without my actions) after the above merge the releaseBranch merges into featureBranch

Why does this occours and how I don't let the second merge happen automatically?

Comment: What is happening, exactly?  There doesn't appear to be enough information in the description to determine what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is a automatically merge without me doing, as exemple above. Branch1 -> Branch2 (i did), Branch2 -> Branch1 (wrong automatically merge). How i stop or I insure it doesn't happen?

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that should happen automatically.  Why do you say there was an automatic merge?  Can you show a screenshot of it?  Without more information, this question will likely be closed as unclear.

Comment: I don't know why it happens automatically, this should not happen in merge between branchs. Srry but i can't post the print the repository on gitlab is of my work